# Accessing windows machine web server from other machines of the Network

Tags: windows-vista, remote, webserver

I have installed wordpress on my Windows Vista machine. And I want other people of my team to access it from my local machine.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have it installed as a site/application under IIS on your machine, then they can access it via:

http://yourmachinename/wordpress-app-name/

If you have the Windows Firewall active, you will need to open up appropriate ports/applications. I recall that there will probably already be an entry ('World Wide Web Service' or similar) that you can enable, or you can simply open up the necessary ports (usually port 80) for your subnet.